# Asserting multiple values in a single element in nightwatch.js

Tags: javascript, string, selenium-webdriver, nightwatch.js

Ok, so what I would like to do is get **all** the values (in this case; colours) in the element(s) listed below;

[image]

I was wondering if I can get all these values/colours from the element in a single function or command?

To complicate things though, the class listed within the element (**seo-crawl-paths__group__link**) is 'dynamic', so the number of classes within the element, and thus the number of values, will change on a daily basis (i.e. tomorrow, only some of the colours will be listed in the element).

Therefore, I can't simply get the value of each individual class within the element, as the number of classes will change.

A command similar to **.getValue()** but for multiple values?

Many thanks :)

Comment: I don't suppose it would be as easy as calling `getValue` on the top-level div, and then splitting the result by newline?  Do you need a mapping of the href to the text value, or just a raw list of the text values?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Nathaniel. I need a raw list of the text values, so I can assert that these values/colours match the values of a string (the result of which is from a dynamic solr query). It’s complicated by the fact that the raw list is ‘dynamic’ and will vary in length from day to day.